# How prove that this estimator is consistent

Tags: estimators

Is my first post, I hope do well.
I have this estimator, from Rao-Blackwell:
$t(t-1)/n(n-1)$ where $t= \sum_{i}^n X_i$. And $X_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}$.
And don't know how prove the consistency. Tchevyshev maybe? I will need the Variance, but I don't know, I'm confused. Please help me if you can. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d $\text{Bernoulli}(\theta)$.

If $\overline X_n$ is the sample mean, your estimator of $\theta^2$ is

$$\widehat{\theta^2}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i-1}{n-1}\right)=\overline X_n\left(\frac{n\overline X_n}{n-1}-\frac1{n-1}\right)$$

Consider each of the three terms separately.

By weak law of large numbers, it is clear that

$$\overline X_n \stackrel{P}\longrightarrow \theta$$

So you are effectively done once you argue that

$$\frac{n}{n-1}\overline X_n \stackrel{P}\longrightarrow \theta$$

Comment: Yess, I don't know how I couldn't see it. n/n-1 go to 1 when n go to infinite. and 1/n-1 go to zero. So I have the sample mean squared that It's what I was looking for. Right?. Thanks you

Comment: This shows that your estimator converges in probability to $\theta(1\cdot \theta)=\theta^2$. Hence proved.